# Windows 8 Can't find executable in path with "where" command

Tags: windows-8, command-line, environment-variables, fontforge

I added the following line in my System Variable Path

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin"
```

I can then run fontforge:

```
C:\Windows\system32>fontforge -v
Copyright (c) 2000-2014 by George Williams. See AUTHORS for Contributors.
 License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 with many parts BSD <http://fontforge.org/license.html>. Please read LICENSE.
 Based on sources from 09:48 AWST  3-Apr-2015-ML-TtfDb-D.
 Based on source from git with hash: 902919cffeaca88f94e2b777f76274ba5d5636ed
no xdefs_filename!
TESTING: getPixmapDir:C:/Program Files (x86)/FontForgeBuilds/share/fontforge/pixmaps
TESTING: getShareDir:C:/Program Files (x86)/FontForgeBuilds/share/fontforge
TESTING: GResourceProgramDir:C:/Program Files (x86)/FontForgeBuilds/bin
trying default theme:C:/Program Files (x86)/FontForgeBuilds/share/fontforge/pixmaps/resources
fontforge 09:48 AWST  3-Apr-2015
libfontforge 20150403
```

But I need to be able to run `where fontforge` from a script. This produces:

```
C:\Windows\system32>where fontforge
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Why can't `where` find the executable path when I have it added to the environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it didn't work, but I re-installed fontforge to a different directory (with no spaces) and it seems to work now.